# Solving unjust enrichment when funds aren’t traceable?

Tags: trust

If a trustee steals money from a trust to pay off an overdrawn bank account, the beneficiary can no longer use subrogation as they no longer have a proprietary interest (due to funds being untraceable).

Therefore if the only solution is a personal remedy of compensation, surely that makes the trustee unjustly enriched as they avoided the interest in the overdrawn bank account?

Comment: In what legal system?

Answer (score 4):

The time value of funds which are used in breach of trust can potentially be a form of unjust enrichment. This is a complex and unsettled area of law, but in general, trustees are liable to [account for the profits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Account_of_profits) of a breach of trust.

However, there is a general [equitable jurisdiction to order the payment of interest](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/5a7c0f4fe5274a13acca311e/0295.pdf#page=20) where money has been misapplied by a trustee. Pre-judgment interest is routinely awarded for common law claims as well. This provides a simpler way for the plaintiff to get compensation in this situation, without pleading a complex unjust enrichment claim.